# Behaviour of print() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can someone justify the behavior of `print()` in the following snippet?

```
print(i for i in range(0,10))
```

I intend to print values from 0 to 9.

Also, how can I know which predefined functions can take let's say `i for i in range(10)` as arguments. (10 separate integers)

Comment: missing brackets? `print([i for i in range(0,10)])`

Comment: or add `print(i)` after `for i in range(0,10)` depending on how you want the output

Comment: `print(*[i for i in range(10)])` -> `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`. You can usual tell by knowing whether the function in question accepts an iterable or multiple arguments.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot people! :D

Comment: then accept one answer so the post is closed

Comment: @martineau No need for comprehensions, `print(*range(10))`

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Very true—good point, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print([i for i in range(0,10)])
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for this, mate. But this makes a list of the values in that specified range. I want the code to print it as: 0123456789

Comment: then add `*` before `[`

Comment: (Assuming you are using python3, otherwise the * won't work there)

Comment: You can delete the 0 in range(0,10). It can just be range(10).

Comment: as @Gaurac Saini said the desired result is 0123456789 so no need for any removal

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `i for i in range(0, 10)` is a generator comprehension, a generator in short is an iterator, you can easily solve it by using joining together what is produced by the generator:

```
# note that range(0, 10) is 
print(''.join(str(i) for i in range(10))) equivalent to range(10)
```

You can even simplify the code a little bit more if you are using Python 3 by:

```
print(*range(10), sep='')
```

**Output:**

```
'0123456789'
```

**More on Generators Comprehensions:**

A generator expression is like a list comprehension (`[i for i in range(10)]`), but instead of finding all the items you're interested and packing them into list, it waits, and yields each item out of the expression, one by one.

**What functions can take stuff as `i for i in range(10)`?**

So in the end this is a collection, so you can pass this to any function that expects a collection.

Comment: You can delete the 0 in range(0,10). It can just be range(10).

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment on Astroms answer:

A bit ugly, but it does the job:

```
print("".join([str(i) for i in range(10)]))
```

Comment: You can delete the 0 in `range(0,10)`. It can just be `range(10)`.

Comment: Oh yeah. :D That was foolish of me to put it there. Thanks for pointing that out! :D

Thanks a lot everyone for the solutions! :D